# How can I combine tooltip tags and paragraph margin tags in a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems combining tooltip tags and paragraph margin settings in a paragraph.

This is what I've got at the moment:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 1px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

p.ex1 {
  margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <font face="Arial" size="4">
        <p class="ex1">
            PARAGRAPH-1 TEST <div class="tooltip">this is a tooltip<span class="tooltiptext"> the tooltip shows this text</span></div> TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST  
        </p>
        <p class="ex1">
            PARAGRAPH-2 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
        </p> 
    </font>
</body>
```

It displays like 3 paragraphs like a new paragraph starts at the tooltip.

What can I do to have this displayed as two paragraphs?

Comment: use `span` instead or make the element `inline`

Comment: what exactly do you mean? what do I need to change in the code?

Comment: `div` is not a valid child of `p`. The browser is trying to fix this mistake by closing the `p` before the `div` and opening a new `p` after it. Use a span instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem you are facing is due to the display of `div` element. Replace your `div` element by `span` element. The problem will be solved!

I have edited your code snippet. Here it is,

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 1px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

p.ex1 {
  margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <font face="Arial" size="4">
        <p class="ex1">
            PARAGRAPH-1 TEST <span class="tooltip">this is a tooltip<span class="tooltiptext"> the tooltip shows this text</span></span> TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST  
        </p>
        <p class="ex1">
            PARAGRAPH-2 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
        </p> 
    </font>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="ex1" >
    PARAGRAPH-1 TEST
    <span class="tooltip">
        this is a tooltip
        <span class="tooltiptext">
            the tooltip shows this text
        </span>
    </span>
    TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST  
</p>
```

Just change `<div>` inside `<p>` tag to span then you have 2 paragraphs.